# How can I make a clickable Lotus Note link in Trello?

Tags: trello

I'd like to create links to my company Lotus Note in Trello, e.g. `notes://DEMUCM01/C125774A004C0544/...`

In the description field, I've read that the Markdown language is possible.

How about in comment area? Is there a way make any clickable link beside `http:\\...`?

Answer (score 2):

Only HTTP(S) links are supported at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a link with Markdown and it works:

```
[something](Notes://server/ABC123...)
```

It also opens a blank tab though.